# how to close MessageBox in RCP plugin development?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created a MessageBox while developing Eclipse plugin which opens when you perform some action...however even after i say "OK" on that messageBox the dialog MessageBox occurs again and again..

Can anyone tell me how to close MessageBox once it is shown to user..

To open dialog box i wrote following code:
    MessageBox dialog = new MessageBox(new Shell(), SWT.OK);
    dialog.setMessage("Some message");
    dialog.setText("Title");
    dialog.open();

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem has nothing to do with the code you posted. Please provide us with additional information. Also consider to set the shell of the currently active widget as parent shell in the **MessageBox** constructor (e.g. **new MessageBox(swtControl.getShell(), SWT.OK)**. Otherwise the dialog might not be modal. This depends on the modal style of the **Shell**.

Answer (score 0):

After research i found that you need to dispose component that you need no longer once specific action has been completed. So once my MessageDialog appears and user clicks 
OK... i need to dispose my MessageDialog using Display.getCurrent().dispose()